# PHP - how to assign value in a whileloop and accessing them on other page

Tags: php

For example this whileloop.

page1.php

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>

  <h2><?php echo $row['sample'];?></h2>
  <a href="page2.php">Page2 Link</a>

<?php
  $_SESSION['samp'] = $row['sample'];
}
?>
```

**FOR EXAMPLE**
 The whileloops displays 3 array h2 tag each with a link tag

```
sample1        sample2        sample3
page2 Link     page2 Link     page2 Link
```

Now in page2.php I want to display the value of the clicked link

```
<h2><?php echo $_SESSION['samp']; ?></h2>
```

My problem is that if I click any of the link tag only the value of the first array is displayed in page2.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are discarding any old values stored in session:

```
$_SESSION['samp'] = $row['sample']; /* overrites */
```

Second, if you can manage to use query string, then you may find it much easier:

```
<a href="page2.php?sample=<?=urlencode($row['sample'])?>">Page2 Link</a>
```

Third, now just use the `$_GET` to get the value of the clicked link:

```
<h2>Sample: <?=$_GET['sample']?></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're assigning to `$_SESSION['samp']` in a `while` loop, thus overwriting the value each time the loop runs. To correct this, you should append to the `$_SESSION['samp']` **array** instead:

```
$_SESSION['samp'][] = $row['sample'];
```

Then you can loop over the array on the second page:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['samp'] as $value) {
  echo "<h2>$value</h2><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you dont need to store the values in session, you can directly send it along with page name and get that value on another page like below

page1.php code like below

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>    
     <h2><?php echo $row['sample'];?></h2>
      <a href="page2.php?sample=<?php echo $row['sample'] ?>">Page2 Link</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

page2.php code like below

```
<?php echo $sample = $_GET['sample'];?>
```

Comment: What if I got more $row[]? Is there any way I dont have to do that code in link tag?